# preg_match returns 1 when searching for alpha charaters in a numeric string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following code snippet and I don't know why such a regex match:

```
<?php

$string = "0123456789";

if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]*/', $string) === 1) {
    echo "match";

}

else {
    echo "not match";

}

?>
```

When the script is run, it always returns "match". I expect it to print out "not match" because there is no alpha characters in the $string variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It matches, because you use the `*` quantifier. It will not match if you use:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

this is because `/[a-zA-Z]*/` will also match 0 occurences.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $string) === 1) {
    echo "match";
}
else {
    echo "not match";
```

`*` means 0 or more, so it was matching the 0 letters at the beginning of the string. You want to match 1, so get rid of `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
/^[A-z]+$/
```

[A-z] will match all the alphabets (both lowercase and uppercase).

^ and $ will make sure that nothing but these alphabets will be matched.

Comment: A-z matches _ and some other characters.